# Sum of reciprocal prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

How can the following equation be proven?

> $$ \forall n > 2 : \sum_{p \le n}{\frac1{p}} = C + \ln\ln n + O\left(\frac1{\ln n}\right), $$  where $p$ is a prime number.

It's not homework; I just don't understand from where should I start.

Comment: [Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apostol gives a proof of this in [his book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA90). Here's a more-or-less condensed version:

> Letting $[p]$ be an Iverson bracket ($1$ if condition $p$ is true, and $0$ if $p$ is false), we have $\sum\limits_{p \le n}\frac1{p}=\sum\limits_{k \le n}\frac{[k\in\mathbb P]}{k}$ Introduce the function $\ell(n)=\sum\limits_{p \le n}\frac{\log\,p}{p}=\sum\limits_{k \le n}\frac{[k\in\mathbb P]\log\,k}{k}$. Making use of (a special case of) Abel's identity,
>
> $$\sum_{y < n \le x}\frac{a(n)}{\log\,n}=\frac{A(x)}{\log\,x}-\frac{A(y)}{\log\,y}+\int_y^x \frac{A(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt$$
>
> where for this case $a(n)=\frac{[n\in\mathbb P]\log\,n}{n}$ and $A(x)=\sum\limits_{k \le x}a(k)$. Taking $y=2$, we have
>
> $$\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}=\frac{\ell(n)}{\log\,n}+\int_2^n \frac{\ell(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt$$
>
> Since $\ell(n)=\log\,n+O(1)$, we then have
>
> $$\begin{align*}\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}&=1+O\left(\frac1{\log\,n}\right)+\int_2^n \frac1{t\log\,t}\mathrm dt+\int_2^n \frac{\mathfrak{R}(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt\\&=1+O\left(\frac1{\log\,n}\right)+\log\log\,n-\log\log\,2+\int_2^n \frac{\mathfrak{R}(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt\end{align*}$$
>
> where $\mathfrak{R}(t)=O(1)$. Since
>
> $$\int_2^n \frac{\mathfrak{R}(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt=\int_2^\infty \frac{\mathfrak{R}(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt+O\left(\frac1{\log\,n}\right)$$
>
> making the appropriate replacements gives
>
> $$\sum_{p \le n}\frac1{p}=\color{blue}{1-\log\log\,2+\int_2^\infty \frac{\mathfrak{R}(t)}{t(\log\,t)^2}\mathrm dt}+\log\log\,n+O\left(\frac1{\log\,n}\right)$$
>
> where the blue part is the constant term $C$ in the OP.

Comment: Note that this proof derives the OP's result from an asymptotic formula for $\ell(n)$, but that asymptotic formula itself is nontrivial.

Comment: He really should look at Apostol anyway... :)

Answer (score 1):

For @clark here is the simple proof i was thinking about :
[image: reciprocal of primes serie diverges]