# Sum of inverse prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

How can the following equation be proven?
$\sum\limits_{p \le n; p \in P} \frac{\ln p}{p} \sim \ln(n) + O(1).$

I just wanna understand this sum 
[Sum of reciprocal prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/sum-of-reciprocal-prime-numbers)

Comment: So what exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: look:   $\sum\limits_{p \le n; p \in P} \frac{\ln p}{p}$ =  $\sum\limits_{x \le n;} \frac{A_1(x)}{x}$. It's ok. And why we can use Shaoiro's theorem and say that it is Ln(x) ??

Answer (score 4):

By partial summation and for Prime Number Theorem in the form $$\pi\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{x}{\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}+O\left(\frac{x}{\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)^{3}}\right)$$
  you have $$\theta\left(N\right)=\underset{p\leq N}{\sum}\log\left(p\right)=\pi\left(N\right)\log\left(N\right)-\int_{2}^{N}\frac{\pi\left(t\right)}{t}dt=$$
 $$=N+O\left(\frac{N}{\left(\log\left(N\right)\right)^{2}}\right)$$
 so $$\underset{p\leq N}{\sum}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p}=\frac{\theta\left(N\right)}{N}+\int_{2}^{N}\frac{\theta\left(t\right)}{t^{2}}dt=$$
 $$=1+O\left(\frac{1}{\left(\log\left(N\right)\right)^{2}}\right)+\int_{2}^{N}\frac{1}{t}dt+O\left(\int_{2}^{N}\frac{1}{t\left(\log\left(t\right)\right)^{2}}dt\right)=$$
 $$=\log\left(N\right)+C+o\left(1\right).$$

Comment: Why? $\theta\left(N\right)=\underset{p\leq N}{\sum}\log\left(p\right)=\pi\left(N\right)\log\left(N\right) ...$ why we can do it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula

Comment: I know about Abel's summation formula. Where in $\underset{p\leq N}{\sum}\log\left(p\right)$ $a_n$ and $f(n)$? How we split $\log(p)$?

Comment: In $\theta\left(N\right)$ you take $a_{p}=1$ and $f(p)=\log\left(p\right)$. So $A(N)=\underset{p\leq N}{\sum}1=\pi\left(N\right)$. The other summation is similar, you take $A(N)=\theta\left(N\right)$.