# Is there a function that can be subtracted from the sum of reciprocals of primes to make the series convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

The gamma constant is defined by an equation where the harmonic series is subtracted by the natural logarithm:

$$\gamma = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n)\right)$$

It is well known that both the harmonic series by itself and the sum of reciprocals of primes are divergent.

Is there a well known function that when subtracted from the sum of reciprocals of primes makes the resultant series convergent?

Is there a function $f(x)$ that makes the following series convergent:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\left(\sum_{p\text{ is a prime }}^n \frac{1}{p} - f(n)\right)$$

Comment: In your summation, do you mean the sum of the first $n$ prime reciprocals, or do you mean primes less than $n$?

Comment: [Mertens' 2nd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant

Comment: @nitin, I mean the first n prime reciprocals.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is a constant associated with the sum of the reciprocals of the primes. In particular, Mertens showed that $$\sum_{p \text{ prime } \le x} \frac1p - \log\log(x)$$ converges to a constant as $x\to \infty$. This is a result from 1874.

I found the result in a paper:

[EULER’S CONSTANT: EULER’S WORK AND MODERN DEVELOPMENTS - By JEFFREY C. LAGARIAS](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-04/S0273-0979-2013-01423-X/S0273-0979-2013-01423-X.pdf)

Mertens' paper is titled: Ein Beitrag zur analytischen Zahlentheorie

Comment: That is an awesome paper, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to see that
$$ -\log n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} $$
is convergent is to write it as
$$ -\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)$$
and check that $\frac{1}{k}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$. In the same way,
$$ \sum_{p}\left(\frac{1}{p}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) $$
is convergent for sure.

Comment: ... although it does leave you with the problem of estimating $\prod_{p \leq n} (1 + 1/p)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: true, but $$\prod_{p\leq n}(1+1/p)\approx\prod_{p\leq n}(1-1/p)^{-1}$$ and the RHS is essentially a truncated harmonic series due to Euler's product.

Answer (score 3):

A heuristic is that an integer $n$ is prime with "probability" one in $\ln n$, and so we can estimate the sum with its "expected" value:

$$ \sum_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{1}{p}
\approx \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k \ln k} \approx \int_2^n \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x \ln x} \approx \ln \ln n$$

In fact, the [Meissel-Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constan) is given by

$$ M = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{1}{p} - \ln \ln n \right) $$

Another heuristic is that the $n$-th prime is approximately $n \ln n$, so

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} \approx \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k \ln k} \approx \int_2^n \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x \ln x} \approx \ln \ln n$$

(the lower bound is tweaked to make the sum well-defined; that's okay since the first few terms contribute a fixed value, and so contribute to the total sum in an asymptotically negligible way)

Note that these two heuristics are compatible:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} = \sum_{\substack{p \leq p_n \\ p \text{ prime}}} 
\frac{1}{p} \approx \ln \ln p_n \approx \ln \ln (n \ln n)
= \ln(\ln n + \ln \ln n) \approx \ln \ln n$$

so the difference between "the first $n$ prime reciprocals" and "the prime reciprocals for primes less than $n$" is asymptotically negligible. In fact, we can estimate

$$ \sum_{\substack{n \leq p \leq p_n \\ p \text{ prime}}} 
\frac{1}{p} \approx \ln \ln p_n - \ln \ln n = \ln \frac{\ln p_n}{\ln n}
\approx \ln \frac{\ln n + \ln \ln n}{\ln n}
\\ = \ln\left(1 + \frac{\ln \ln n}{\ln n}\right) \approx \frac{\ln \ln n}{\ln n}
$$

Answer (score 2):

By [Sum of reciprocal prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/sum-of-reciprocal-prime-numbers),

$$\sum_{p \le n}{\frac1{p}} = C + \ln\ln n + O\left(\frac1{\ln n}\right)$$

Therefore $\ln \ln n$ fits the bill.