# Order of Magnitude

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is well known (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/sum-of-reciprocal-prime-numbers), for example) that we have

$$
\psi\left(\frac{1}{2},T\right)=\sum_{p\leq T}\frac{1}{p}=\log(\log T)+A+O\left(\frac{1}{\log T}\right),
$$
where $\psi(\sigma,T)=\sum_{p\leq T}p^{-2\sigma}$, $p$ denotes a prime number, and $A$ is some constant.

I'm interested in which $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$ the sum has essentially the same order (note that I'm not asking about convergence/divergence; clearly it converges, but $\log(\log T)$ might still well approximate the sum).

**What I've done**

If we put $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}+\omega(T)$, we have
$$
\psi(\sigma,T)=\sum_{p\leq T}\frac{p^{-2\omega(T)}}{p}=\sum_{p\leq T}\frac{1-2\omega(T)\log(p)+\cdots}{p}.
$$
Thus, if $\omega(T)$ is "nice" enough, we have
$$
\psi(\sigma,T)=\log(\log T)+2\omega(T)\log(T)+O(\omega(T)).\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Thus, it would seem that as long as $\omega(T)=O\left(\frac{\log(\log T)}{\log T}\right)$, the order of magnitude is essentially the same.

**My Question**

Is this correct? Can it be streamlined/improved? I'm staring at a paper of Atle Selberg that makes it seem like $\omega(T)=O((\log T)^{-\delta})$ for some "fixed positive" $\delta$ should hold. While I think at the moment that my work is correct, I'm not convinced it is what he had in mind when he wrote the passage.

($\dagger$) I realize I am sweeping some details under the rug here; if necessary, I can post them, but it seems fruitless to do so at the moment.

Comment: Be careful sweeping details under the rug as something is not right with how you truncated the exponential series and put in a big-O term. In particular, we should not have $O(\omega(T))$ on the right hand side. For monotonic $\omega$, if $$\omega(t)=o\left(\frac{1}{\log t}\right)$$ then you will have a main term of $\log \log x$. If $$\omega(t)=\frac{c}{\log t}\left(1+o(1)\right),$$ then you will have a main term of $e^{-2c} \log \log x$, and for $\omega(t)$ larger than this, the sum will not behave like $\log \log x$ anymore.

Comment: To see this, note that the relevant integral is $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{t^{-2\omega(x)}}{t\log t}dt,$$ and it satisfies $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{t^{-2\omega(t)}}{t\log t}dt\geq\int_{2}^{x}\frac{t^{-2\omega(x)}}{t\log t}dt\geq x^{-2\omega(x)}\log\log x.$$

Comment: @EricNaslund:  You're right that my estimate wasn't correct. I fleshed out the details for how I was thinking about it and found that my hoped-for estimate didn't work out. I'll keep working on it, but thank you.